# not able to see the log statements in ddms

Tags: android-emulator, http-headers, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to install my worklight application on the android htc mobile. The application was getting installed successfully but the problem is I am  not able to see the log messages.As soon as I connect my device it is giving me the following errors:
1) "couldn't find the mandatory host http header" 
2)"addition of standard header pragma is discouraged as a future version of the RESTlet API will directly support it"

Can anyone please help me in solving this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The question's description text is not very helpful... can you please elaborate?

1. What is "htc mobile", is there a specific device model and Android OS version?
2. What do you mean by "log messages"? Are you referring to the output in LogCat?
3. Can you try with a NEW - unmodified - Worklight app (with the Android environment) and see if you still get these errors?
4. Do you see Worklight-related logs regardless of these errors? Is the app working?

Right now this does not seem to be a Worklight-related issue.

There are some questions already in Stackoverflow that seem to touch these supposed issues. You can go over them:

- [Android LogCat continuously repeating a warning: "Addition of standard header .... not allowed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319905/android-logcat-continuously-repeating-a-warning-addition-of-standard-header)
- [Logcat continously shows messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892694/logcat-continously-shows-messages)

A common thread between them seems to be some OTHER app that is leaking. Try closing as many apps before installing the Worklight app.

In LogCat you can also [create a filter](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html) to see log messages related ONLY to the app, and not to anything else that may be happening in the device (with other apps).

Comment: 1.mobile device that I am using for testing are htc mobile with android version 2.3.5.   2)logmessages in the sense in my worklight application i write debug statements like WL.Logger.debug("button#add Called"); These statements I am not able to see in logcat.

Comment: the emulator version i am using is 4.0.4

Comment: This happens in both the emulator and device? what about questions 3 and 4 in my answer?